# for Loop multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am trying to create a new variable (column) which values depend on the values of other variable, therefore I try to create a for loop with multiple conditions.

Here is the code that I tried:

```
ABC_Levels = []
for i in range(len(df_ABC)):
    if df_ABC.loc[i,'ABC']>=5.7:
        ABC_Levels.append('High')
    elif df_ABC.loc[i,'ABC']<5.4:
        ABC_Levels.append('Low')
    else:
        ABC_Levels.append('Intermediate')
ABC_Levels
```

It returns the following error:

KeyError: 0

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

I guess that is something related with the first row because if I change the code for this one:

```
ABC_Levels = []
for i in range(len(df_ABC['ABC'])):
    if df_ABC.loc[i]>=5.7:
        ABC_Levels.append('High')
    elif df_ABC.loc[i]<5.4:
        ABC_Levels.append('Low')
    else:
        ABC_Levels.append('Intermediate')
ABC_Levels
```

It returns the value of the first row.

I'll appreciate any help

Comment: You're making us guess where the error is.  Please edit the question and add the full error traceback message.

Comment: What is result of `print(df)`? Ideally provide a [mre].

Comment: You shouldn't use `loc` for positional indexing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not an answer (at least a full one), but personally I would try to use `np.select` instead of enumerating the dataframe. For example:

```py
series = df_ABC['ABC']
conds = [series >= 5.7, series < 5.4]
choices = ['High', 'Low'] 
np.select(conds, choices, default='Intermediate').tolist()
```

**UPD**

Modification which worked for OP:

```py
conditions = [ (df_ABC['ABC'] >= 5.7), (df_ABC['ABC'] <= 5.4) ] 
choices = ['High', 'Low'] 
df_ABC['ABC_expression'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Intermediate')
df_ABC
```

Comment: Hi all, it works using a Guru method, with a slight modification 'conditions = [
    (df_ABC['ABC'] >= 5.7),
    (df_ABC['ABC'] <= 5.4)
]
choices = ['High', 'Low']
df_ABC['ABC_expression'] = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Intermediate')
df_ABC' Thank you every much for the help

Comment: Im new here, I marked as 'like' but never 'solved'. Now is marked as accepted!!!